# Using Microsoft Windows Standard Style in WPF-Window?

Tags: wpf, window, styles

Is it posible to use the Microsoft Windows Standard Style in a WPF-window? If I create a normal WPF-Window with a textblock or something like that, the font is very small and not the same like in Microsoft Windows. The background of the window is white. Maybe you can tell me how to use the Style or an information source or things like that, where I can read the settings of a Microsoft Windows Standard window, like:

- Font Family/Size
- Margins (In Buttons, windows, groupboxes,..)
- Paddings
- Colors (Backgroundcolor,..)
- etc..

Comment: What do you mean by the Windows standard style? Can you link to a picture of what you'd like?

Comment: http://windowsclient.net/wf/blogs/mhendersblog/Oct10Post/Figure1.png

Comment: I'm assuming that this application will be running on Windows XP? Otherwise, the default style was significantly updated with Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the system defined values for your application, have a look at these 3 classes :

- [`System.Windows.SystemFonts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemfonts.aspx)
- [`System.Windows.SystemParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx)
- [`System.Windows.SystemColors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx)

Example (from MSDN):

```
Button btncsharp = new Button();
btncsharp.Content = "SystemFonts";
btncsharp.Background = SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrush;
btncsharp.FontSize = SystemFonts.IconFontSize;
btncsharp.FontWeight = SystemFonts.MessageFontWeight;
btncsharp.FontFamily = SystemFonts.CaptionFontFamily;
cv1.Children.Add(btncsharp);
```

OR, in XAML:

```
<Button
     FontSize="{x:Static SystemFonts.IconFontSize}"
     FontWeight="{x:Static SystemFonts.MessageFontWeight}"
     FontFamily="{x:Static SystemFonts.CaptionFontFamily}"
     Background="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}">
     SystemFonts 
</Button>
```

Check these links at MSDN for more : [System.Windows.SystemFonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemfonts.aspx), [System.Windows.SystemParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx), and [System.Windows.SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx)

Quick Tip : Use Visual Studio IntelliSence to see a list of properties in these class